# VBA WORD: Remove SHIFT-ENTER lines

Tags: vba, ms-word, powerpoint

After copying from ppt, you often get lines that look like this:

```
This is a line
and then another line
and then another
and so forth. New lines created 
via SHIFT-ENTER.
```

Where I need it to say:

> This is a line
>       and then another line
>       and then another
>       and so forth. New lines created 
>       via SHIFT-ENTER.

New lines created by just pressing ENTER should remain as new lines.

Comment: Hi again... I guess this is a continuation of the other question of yours... I could guess that you copy entire `paragraph` of text while you should copy without `ending paragraph mark`. If my tip isn't enough for you to solve it on your own please, add that part of your code which set `text range` and do the `copy` trick...

Comment: Thanks for your help. I think I was looking for the 'ending paragraph mark' I just didn't know what it was called. I'll see what I can do now :)

Comment: Should I just find-replace to remove the manual-new-line characters?

Comment: Rather try to cut last (invisible) mark. However, there could be another problem- which way do you past text to your Word document. Check if you don't insert `new paragraph marks` there before paste...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> is nothing but `^l`

This is how <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> looks like

[image]

So you can either replace it manually or use the below VBA Code.

**Non VBA Way**

1. Press Ctrl+H to open the Replace dialog.
2. In the "Find what" box, type `^l`.
3. In the "Replace with" box, type `" "` (Space without the quotes).
4. Click Replace All.

**VBA Way**

Paste this in a module

```
Sub Sample()
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "^l"
        .Replacement.Text = " "
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchKashida = False
        .MatchDiacritics = False
        .MatchAlefHamza = False
        .MatchControl = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This page on the PPT FAQ I maintain explains the characters that PPT uses for linebreaks vs paragraph endings.  It varies somewhat across versions and shape types.

Paragraph endings and line breaks
http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00992_Paragraph_endings_and_line_breaks.htm